Use of code tag backticks / grave accents `` to mark up sinographs
I have seen a lot of people use backticks / grave accents (``) around sinographs, resulting in the browser rendering it as code. They are already monospaced, so why?
If my intuition is anything to go by, people want to separate the different languages, or it changes the default font used. This could be accomplished in more elegant ways (e.g. adapting what the Japanese SX is doing, maybe applying some styling to size/background).

Where are you seeing these issues?

@user3306356 Just to name a few, there are some here: 215, 3083, 3304, and in the comments here 6298, 3519

It's normally done for emphasis. Due to italics rendering for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ming_(typefaces) fonts being really horrible, especially with smaller font sizes, this form of emphasis is heavily avoided and we have one less way to emphasise our text...

I see, I was a bit too quick to conclusions here. Have you considered text-emphasis? Or using colors? The default style for <code> is ≈⅕ smaller font size, which is a bit counterproductive for emphasis.

Related: Abuse of code formatting to add unnecessary emphasis and its duplicate link. The problem with using code block for emphasizing is the accessibility issue with screen readers.

I don't know how these things work; I understand that they're not features already available to Chinese SE, and that we have to request them from Meta? Sorry ><
